# getting error "modulenotfounderror: No module named 'google'" but when trying to install through command prompt it says requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, eclipse

Pretty self-explanatory, trying to do a small web scraper from a google search, but when trying to import, using "`from google import search`" I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'.

When trying to install google again from the command prompt using "`pip install google`" I get the error: 
Requirement already satisfied: google in `c:\users\dsimard\python\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)`
Requirement already satisfied: `beautifulsoup4` in `c:\users\dsimard\python\lib\site-packages (from google) (4.6.0)`

I am writing this program in eclipse.

Comment: Is your interpreter set to that python instance? It could be pointing to a base install

Comment: It should be, I had to do the same process for requests & beautifulsoup4 and both of those import fine

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`, and show us the result of running this Python code in eclipse: `import sys; print (sys.version)`

Comment: the output is: pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\dsimard\python\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)                                                                                                                                        the result of the print(sys.version) is 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Well, that's odd.  Is `c:\users\dsimard\python\lib\site-packages` on your `PYTHONPATH`?  Show us the output of `print (sys.path)`.

Comment: the output for print(sys.path) is: ['C:\\Users\\dsimard\\eclipse-workspace\\WebScraper', 'C:\\Users\\dsimard\\eclipse-workspace\\WebScraper', 'C:\\Users\\dsimard\\Python\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\dsimard\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\dsimard\\Python', 'C:\\Users\\dsimard\\Python\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\dsimard\\Python\\python37.zip']

Answer (score 0):

Try `from googlesearch import search`

Comment: What does the from command do? (well it doesn't generally exist - could you be more specific? Thanks.)